# Android: Possible Bug in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, android-relativelayout

I have two `Views` I am using to arrange some `buttons` on the screen. The screen size I am seeing the result on is **Moto G** in landscape mode - **640dp * 360dp**. The problem is - the `buttons` are arranging them according to the View with `id=center_parent` instead of the the one with `id=left_corner`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"/>

   <View android:id="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_marginRight="165dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>"

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:text="1"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
      android:text="2"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="292dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
      android:text="3"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="292dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
      android:text="4"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

</RelativeLayout>!
```

Attached is the **image** of how it looks on the screen. Even though the arrows show that is measure using left_corner, but is not the case. If I replace `left_corner` with `center_parent` in the `buttons` while arranging the result is the same.

[The marked arrow is left_corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9gAh.png)

I have found an alternative. So alternative is not what I am looking for. I will love to learn the explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

The `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginRight` are too much.

Remove all the margins first, you will see the view properly. Then start addding the margins again accordingly.

There are few things you need to observer here.

`layout_marginBottom` pushing left_corner too far up from center_parent

`layout_marginRight` is pushing left_corner too far from center_parent
you have to make up your mind on where you want the controls to be places and aligned to what.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="10dp"/>

   <View android:id="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_width="10dp"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/center_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>"

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:text="1"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

   <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="2"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:text="3"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:padding="0dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/left_corner"
      android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
      android:text="4"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:background="@drawable/star"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

using the above xml, i got the below output.
[image: Preview]

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem in this case. Moto g - width in landscape = 640dp. left_corner = 165dp marginRight from the center. And button one = 165dp marginLeft from left_corner. So it should be basically at the center of the screen (horizontally). How can you say margins are too much

Comment: @Mohan - Also I trried to specify the `margin_right` and `margin_bottom` for the `button1` as 0dp and to a surprise it overlapped the `center_parent` view

Comment: Sir, I agree with your edit. But, think a little mathematically. Screen size = `360dp x 640dp` (in `landscape` mode). left_corner=`165dp` towards left and `150dp` above the center of the screen (center_parent). And btn1 is towards right (`165dp`) and below left_corner. So btn1 should be above center_parent and almost in line with the left_corner horizontally. How can you say margin is too much.  P.S I am using `full screen` mode